# Attempted exploit via Catalog Advanced Search?

Tags: magento-1.8, security

I just noticed a few suspicious crash reports on my site for someone accessing the "Catalog Advanced Search" page.  However, that link is not exposed anywhere on my site, so someone is accessing a known Magento URL and perhaps attempting some kind of exploit via that URL?

I have all the latest patches, are there known exploits using the Advanced Catalog Search?

I don't know if that URL is used under the covers at all by the Magento implementation, would it be safe for me to do a 403 redirect in my .htaccess for that URL?

Update: Someone suggested it would be useful to know the URLs of the strange requests I'm seeing.  I looked at the error reports and there were nine request during the same second that all resulted resulted in the same exception:

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away

Here are the requests...

> /shop/catalog/product_compare/add/product/16/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5waWNrbC1pdC5jb20vc2hvcC9jYXRhbG9nc2VhcmNoL2FkdmFuY2VkL3Jlc3VsdC8_bW9kZT1saXN0/
>   /shop/catalogsearch/advanced/result?description=1&jars=1&name=..%c0%af..%c0%af..%c0%af..%c0%af..%c0%af..%c0%af..%c0%af..%c0%afetc/passwd&size[]=8&price[from]=1&price[to]=1&short_description=1&sku=1&tax_class_id[]=0&width=1
>   /shop/catalogsearch/advanced/result?description=1&jars=1&name=sekinchw&size[]=result&price[from]=1&price[to]=1&short_description=1&sku=1&tax_class_id[]=4&width=1
>   /shop/catalogsearch/advanced/result?description=966869&jars=1&name=seehlqve&size[]=8&price[from]=1&price[to]=1&short_description=1&sku=1&tax_class_id[]=0&width=1
>   /shop/catalogsearch/advanced/result?description=
>   /shop/catalogsearch/advanced/result?description=1&jars=1&name=cpdqfrdc&size[]=9&price[from]=1&price[to]=1&short_description=1&sku=1&tax_class_id[]=2&width=1
>   /shop/catalog/product_compare/add/..%5c..%5c..%5c..%5c..%5c..%5c..%5c..%5cwindows%5cwin.ini/17/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5waWNrbC1pdC5jb20vc2hvcC9jYXRhbG9nc2VhcmNoL2FkdmFuY2VkL3Jlc3VsdC8_ZGlyPWFzYyZvcmRlcj1uYW1l/
>   /shop/catalogsearch/advanced/result?description=1&jars=1&name=obioeuth&size[]=8&price[from]=1&price[to]=1&short_description=)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))&sku=1&tax_class_id[]=4&width=1
>   /shop/catalogsearch/advanced/result?description=1'%22&jars=1&name=seehlqve&size[]=8&price[from]=1&price[to]=1&short_description=1&sku=1&tax_class_id[]=0&width=1

Comment: Would be interesting to see what the URLs look like. If you don't want to publish them, you could also file a report to security@magento.com

Comment: Added the URLs as requested.

Answer (score 1):

There  two way, we can prevent this url:

### redirection

One redirect to **catalogsearch/advanced/result** and  /`catalogsearch/advanced/ http://example.com/`  to site `http://example.com/` ,so that **suspicious  user or any user** cannot access that url.

### Add form key:

Or add magento **form_key** to form and  validate that form to post url:
Add form key that form by  this code <`?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>`

Comment: Where can I read more about 'form_key' functionality?